# parsing xml with attributesn in java

Tags: java, android

below is my xml code in which i need to display each node's attributes i.e name and type.

xml :

```
<node label="Tree Data">
<node name="View" type="Page">
<node name="Organisational Structure" type="Page"/>
<node name="Experience" type="Page"/>
<node name="Expertise" type="Language">
<node name="Flex" type="Language"/>
<node name="Android" type="Language"/>
<node name="Java" type="Language"/>
</node>
<node name="Project" type="Project">
<node name="Sabre" type="Project"/>
<node name="Android Project" type="Project"/>
<node name="Media Framework" type="Project"/>
<node name="CCD" type="Project"/>
<node name="Redbus" type="Project"/>
<node name="India Today" type="Project"/>
<node name="Money Control" type="Project"/>
</node>
</node>
<node name="Reorganize" type="Action"/>
<node name="Add New Employee" type="Action">
<node name="Dir" type="Page"/>
<node name="P.M" type="Page"/>
<node name="S.E" type="Page"/>
<node name="JUN" type="Page"/>
<node name="EMP" type="Page"/>
</node>
<node name="Add Project Members" type="Action"/>
</node>
```

i am getting the following output  :

output:

```
01-23 17:13:26.047: I/System.out(3846): name : 
01-23 17:13:26.057: I/System.out(3846): type : 
01-23 17:13:26.057: I/System.out(3846): name : View
01-23 17:13:26.077: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.077: I/System.out(3846): name : Organisational Structure
01-23 17:13:26.077: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): name : Experience
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): name : Expertise
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): type : Language
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): name : Flex
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): type : Language
01-23 17:13:26.117: I/System.out(3846): name : Android
01-23 17:13:26.117: I/System.out(3846): type : Language
01-23 17:13:26.117: I/System.out(3846): name : Java
01-23 17:13:26.128: I/System.out(3846): type : Language
01-23 17:13:26.128: I/System.out(3846): name : Project
01-23 17:13:26.139: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.139: I/System.out(3846): name : Sabre
01-23 17:13:26.139: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.147: I/System.out(3846): name : Android Project
01-23 17:13:26.147: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): name : Media Framework
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): name : CCD
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): name : Redbus
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): name : India Today
01-23 17:13:26.177: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): name : Money Control
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): name : Reorganize
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): type : Action
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): name : Add New Employee
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): type : Action
01-23 17:13:26.197: I/System.out(3846): name : Dir
01-23 17:13:26.197: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): name : P.M
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): name : S.E
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): name : JUN
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.228: I/System.out(3846): name : EMP
01-23 17:13:26.228: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.237: I/System.out(3846): name : Add Project Members
01-23 17:13:26.237: I/System.out(3846): type : Action
```

but i actually need the following output :

desired output :

```
01-23 17:13:26.057: I/System.out(3846): name : View
01-23 17:13:26.077: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.077: I/System.out(3846): name : Organisational Structure
01-23 17:13:26.077: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): name : Experience
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): name : Expertise
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): type : Language
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): name : Flex
01-23 17:13:26.097: I/System.out(3846): type : Language
01-23 17:13:26.117: I/System.out(3846): name : Android
01-23 17:13:26.117: I/System.out(3846): type : Language
01-23 17:13:26.117: I/System.out(3846): name : Java
01-23 17:13:26.128: I/System.out(3846): type : Language
01-23 17:13:26.128: I/System.out(3846): name : Project
01-23 17:13:26.139: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.139: I/System.out(3846): name : Sabre
01-23 17:13:26.139: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.147: I/System.out(3846): name : Android Project
01-23 17:13:26.147: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): name : Media Framework
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): name : CCD
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): name : Redbus
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.167: I/System.out(3846): name : India Today
01-23 17:13:26.177: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): name : Money Control
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): type : Project
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): name : Reorganize
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): type : Action
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): name : Add New Employee
01-23 17:13:26.187: I/System.out(3846): type : Action
01-23 17:13:26.197: I/System.out(3846): name : Dir
01-23 17:13:26.197: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): name : P.M
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): name : S.E
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): name : JUN
01-23 17:13:26.217: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.228: I/System.out(3846): name : EMP
01-23 17:13:26.228: I/System.out(3846): type : Page
01-23 17:13:26.237: I/System.out(3846): name : Add Project Members
01-23 17:13:26.237: I/System.out(3846): type : Action
```

java code :

```
package com.example.xmlparsevdatr;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Document dom;

    public MainActivity() {
        MainActivity();

        ArrayList<Element> listGroup = getGroups();

    }

    private ArrayList getGroups() {
        try {
            Element documentElement = (Element) dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList childNodes = documentElement.getElementsByTagName("node");

            for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {

                if (childNodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) childNodes.item(i);
                    String name = element.getAttribute("name");
                    String type = element.getAttribute("type");
                    System.out.println("name : " + name);
                    System.out.println("type : " + type);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;

    }

    private void MainActivity() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        // System.out.println("Inside xml");

        try {
            String sURL = "http://192.168.2.6/cgi-bin/EmployeeTreeCgi/TreeStrutRet.cgi?Username=admin@ohile.com";
            URL url = new URL(sURL);
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            dom = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this question is a good fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Besides, your first node doesn't have a `name` neither a `type` attribute, that's why you are getting blank values, you have to skip it.

Comment: `Element.hasAttribute(String element)` will do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML does not seem to be good.

The `first <node>` element `does not` have `name` and `type` attributes.

Ideally, while using XML you shouldn't have the parent and child having same name. For example, the XML should be like :

```
<books>
    <book id=1/>
    <book id=2/>
</books>
```

Also, please consider properly `formatting your XML` for better readability.

**EDIT:**

There can be a check before retrieving any attribute as:

```
if(childNodes.item(i).hasAttribute("name")) {
    // print the name
}
```

Comment: yes you are rite.but i can't change this xml because it has been given to me by some third party. so i want to know is there any way possible with in the original xml to avoid first name and type field from blank.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to print the name and type of the first node, which don't exist. Therefore you get the first two lines in your output.

Try checking if the element actually has a name and type before printing it.